# Binding numpad keys on i3 don't work

Tags: x11, i3

I have been trying to bind numpad numeric keys on i3 unsuccessfully. This seems like a simple enough thing to do but it doesn't work. And I can't figure out why.

**Keyboard layout: English US Default**

For example:

```
bindsym $mod+KP_1 workspace $ws1
```

Does not do anything.

```
bindcode $mod+$KP_1 workspace $ws1
```

Errors out saying that there is an error in my i3 config with the following errors:

```
ERROR: Could not parse "$mod+$KP_1" as an input code, ignoring this binding.
```

`$mod` and `$KP_1` was set to `133` and `87` prior to running the bindcode.

There is comment in [GitHub](https://github.com/i3/i3/issues/2558#issuecomment-260770392) saying that numpad **keys cannot be used**. Is that true ?

**Does no one have bindings like `$mod + KP_2` or something ?**

Comment: How about `bindcode $mod+87`, but leaving `$mod` set as `Mod4`? Or `bindsym $mod+KP_End` / `KP_Down`, etc. Also check output of `xev` with numlock off for keysyms.

Comment: @thisaccounthasbeen Solved. Posted the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Solved. They should really add this into the documentation. Thanks to the guys on the IRC channel for helping me with this.

Ok since `KP_0` and `KP_1` keys are on the numpad they will only work in the numeric fashion when `numlock` is turned on, otherwise they are `KP_END`, `KP_HOME`, etc. Now for a normal human being that's fine, but the reason this does not work on **`i3` is because `i3` needs to be told `numlock` is on.** **It is not smart enough to figure that by itself.**

So the keybindings need to be written accordingly. So the correct keybindings would be:

```
bindsym $mod+mod2+KP_1 workspace $ws1
bindsym $mod+mod2+KP_2 workspace $ws2
bindsym $mod+mod2+KP_3 workspace $ws3
bindsym $mod+mod2+KP_4 workspace $ws4
bindsym $mod+mod2+KP_5 workspace $ws5
bindsym $mod+mod2+KP_6 workspace $ws6
bindsym $mod+mod2+KP_7 workspace $ws7
bindsym $mod+mod2+KP_8 workspace $ws8
```

The obvious question is what is `mod2` ? Well just run `xmodmap` and you will find out. Most of the time it will be `NumLock`.

Now looking at this configuration it may look like that I am adding another keypress to my bindings but that is not so. Since `numlock` will already be `ON` I can just press the first modifier and the numpad key. I don't have to press `mod2`, **since its "already pressed", so to speak**.

So I can just press: Super(mod) and KP_1 on my keyboard to switch the workspace to 1.

A recommendation is to use a program like `numlockx` to always turn on login.

Comment: Thank you! But in my setup this solution does not work 100%. Switching workspaces Does work the way, you describe, but moving a focused window to a workspace does not. What am I missing?
`bindsym $super+mod2+KP_1 workspace $ws1` => works
`bindsym $super+Shift+mod2+KP_1 move container to workspace $ws1` => does not work

Answer (score 2):

If you also want to move windows to the workspace by adding a shift modifier remember that numpad numbers translate into numpad commands (e.g. `KP_1` -> `KP_End`). You can use `xmodmap -pke | grep KP_` to find out which number corresponds to which command. Wierdly you still need to specify mumlock (mod2) and shift explicitly in i3. This works for me:

```
bindsym $mod+mod2+KP_1 workspace $ws1
bindsym $mod+mod2+Shift+KP_End move container to workspace $ws1
```

Edit: Just found this exact workaround in the mentioned [Github](https://github.com/i3/i3/issues/2558#issuecomment-405577744) issue. Too late, but oh  well :D

Answer (score 0):

Well.. it costed me around 6 hours to do it. So I'm going to make a simple resume how I did it:

I have two monitors so I did fallowing:

I created a file `workspaces.conf` and inside I did this:

```
# assign workspaces to screens
workspace 1  output $Monitor_left
workspace 2  output $Monitor_left
...
workspace 9  output $Monitor_left
workspace 10 output $Monitor_left

workspace 11 output $Monitor_right
workspace 12 output $Monitor_right
...
workspace 19 output $Monitor_right
workspace 20 output $Monitor_right

# Define names for default workspaces for which we configure key bindings later on.
# We use variables to avoid repeating the names in multiple places.
set $ws01 "1"
set $ws02 "2"
....
set $ws09 "9"
set $ws00 "10"

set $ws11 "11"
...
set $ws19 "19"
set $ws20 "20"
```

and if you have 2 or more monitors PLEASE name the `WS`s as `ws01`, `ws02`, `ws03`,... instead of `ws1`, `ws2`, `ws3`. (I'll tell you why later ;D ).

After doing it you can include this file inside of yours i3config

**config**

```
include $HOME/.config/i3/workspaces.conf
```

After that, make sure to add the super keys
(just use the command `xmodmap`)

```
#Master key Super "Windows" and Alt Left "alt"
(soon you will understand why 2 mod keys)

    set $mod Mod4
    set $mod_alt Mod1
```

And now set your monitors inside of variables (you can use the command `xrand` and findout what is the output)

```
set $Monitor_left DP-0
set $Monitor_right HDMI-0
```

Now make the confs to switch to the workspaces, something like this:

```
# switch to workspace
# Monitor1
bindsym $mod+mod2+KP_1  workspace $ws01 ; move workspace to output $Monitor_left
bindsym $mod+mod2+KP_2  workspace $ws02 ; move workspace to output $Monitor_left
 ......
bindsym $mod+mod2+KP_9  workspace $ws09 ; move workspace to output $Monitor_left
bindsym $mod+mod2+KP_0  workspace $ws00 ; move workspace to output $Monitor_left

# Monitor2
bindsym $mod_alt+mod2+KP_1   workspace $ws11 ; move workspace to output $Monitor_right
bindsym $mod_alt+mod2+KP_2   workspace $ws12 ; move workspace to output $Monitor_right
.....
bindsym $mod_alt+mod2+KP_9   workspace $ws19 ; move workspace to output $Monitor_right
bindsym $mod_alt+mod2+KP_0   workspace $ws20 ; move workspace to output $Monitor_right
```

it's almost perfect :)
From now on, you can use `superkey+number` (windows_key) / `superkey+numpad_number` to switch to ALL workspaces (1-10) on your left monitor and `alt_left+numpad_number` to switch to ALL workspaces (11-20) on your right monitor

Moving containers to other workspacies!
To do it you can just copy this lines here OR use the command `xmodmap -pke | grep KP_` to find the right keys

```
# move focused container to workspace 
# (monitor1 numpad)
bindsym $mod+Mod2+Shift+KP_End move container to workspace    $ws01 
bindsym $mod+Mod2+Shift+KP_Down move container to workspace   $ws02 
bindsym $mod+Mod2+Shift+KP_Next move container to workspace   $ws03 
bindsym $mod+Mod2+Shift+KP_Left move container to workspace   $ws04 
bindsym $mod+Mod2+Shift+KP_Begin move container to workspace  $ws05 
bindsym $mod+Mod2+Shift+KP_Right move container to workspace  $ws06 
bindsym $mod+Mod2+Shift+KP_Home move container to workspace   $ws07 
bindsym $mod+Mod2+Shift+KP_Up move container to workspace     $ws08 
bindsym $mod+Mod2+Shift+KP_Prior move container to workspace  $ws09
bindsym $mod+Mod2+Shift+KP_Insert move container to workspace $ws00

# (Monitor2 numpad)
bindsym $mod_alt+Mod2+Shift+KP_End move container to workspace    $ws11 
bindsym $mod_alt+Mod2+Shift+KP_Down move container to workspace   $ws12 
bindsym $mod_alt+Mod2+Shift+KP_Next move container to workspace   $ws13 
bindsym $mod_alt+Mod2+Shift+KP_Left move container to workspace   $ws14 
bindsym $mod_alt+Mod2+Shift+KP_Begin move container to workspace  $ws15 
bindsym $mod_alt+Mod2+Shift+KP_Right move container to workspace  $ws16 
bindsym $mod_alt+Mod2+Shift+KP_Home move container to workspace   $ws17 
bindsym $mod_alt+Mod2+Shift+KP_Up move container to workspace     $ws18 
bindsym $mod_alt+Mod2+Shift+KP_Prior move container to workspace  $ws19
bindsym $mod_alt+Mod2+Shift+KP_Insert move container to workspace $ws20
```

I have never used the i3bar and I don't know how to config it. BUT if you are using polybar then you NEED to config like this:

[module/i3]
...

```
ws-icon-0 = "00;X"
ws-icon-1 = "01;I"
ws-icon-2 = "02;II"
ws-icon-3 = "03;III"
ws-icon-4 = "04;IV"
ws-icon-5 = "05;V"
ws-icon-6 = "06;VI"
ws-icon-7 = "07;VII"
ws-icon-8 = "08;VIII"
ws-icon-9 = "09;IX"
```

notice that if you try to call the WSs like this: `ws-icon-1 = "1;I"` it will get in conflict with the `ws` number 11

**BUG by system start**

I noticed that everytime when I started my system my i3 started in the workflow1 (`$mod+1`) instead of workflow01(`$mod+mod2+KP_1`). So I created a mini script in python that solves that problem

config_workflow.py

```
import pyautogui

p=pyautogui

p.hotkey('win', 'right')
p.hotkey('altleft', 'num1')
p.hotkey('win', 'left')
p.hotkey('win', 'num1')
```

and of course I start the script every time when my i3 starts (i3 autostart)
I don't know if there is a better way to solve it, BUT this was the only way I found.